# pause SFSpeechRecognizer on button click

Tags: ios, swift, sfspeechrecognizer

Hello i am creating `Call Recording App` and i am playing recording  through app using `AVAduioPlayer` and also transcribe audio to text Using `SFSpeechRecognizer` below is my code for playing audio and transcribe using below code

```
func requestSpeectAuth(){
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
            if authStatus == SFSpeechRecognizerAuthorizationStatus.authorized{
                if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "audio", withExtension: "m4a"){
                    print(path)
                    do {
                        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
                        self.audiPlayer = sound
                        sound.play()
                    } catch {
                        print("Error")
                    }
                    let reconizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
                    let request = SFSpeechURLRecognitionRequest(url: path)
                    self.recpnizer?.recognitionTask(with: request){ (result,error) in
                        if let error = error{
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }else{
                            print(result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)
                            self.txtView.text = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and i successfully done this but now when i pause audio at that time i need to stop  Transcription is there any way to to stop `SFSpeechRecognizer` on button click then please help me

Answer (score 0):

When you calling installTap, there will be one block which let you append audio buffer to the recognitionRequest, just don't append the audio to buffer when you want to pause.